# online editing of office document stored on webserver in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, outlook, ms-office

Any suggestions on how to online editing Office documents, stored on the local web solution? 
I have a website build with asp.net, and some documents uploaded to that website, that it shall be possible to edit online.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using DevExpress, they have components for editing Excel and Word.

@sparky42 Thanks very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options. Some versions of Office (Not the web version) support WebDAV and the newer option, WOPI.  WOPI is also used with the Web online version of Office.

There are a few .NET examples of these around. Here's a WebDAV server:
[WebDAV](https://bitbucket.org/AdamMil/webdav.server/overview)

Here's a WOPI server:
[WOPI](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost)

Word, for example, will test the server when opening a file to see what it supports.
More on opening a file from a URI in Word/Office can be found by search for the Office URI schemes e.g. ms-excel:ofv|u|....